# Need to update User lookup through vf using Picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce

when running this code, i cant see any values in debug log onchange and i have to update them. please guide me if i am wrong any where.
Vf Page

```
<apex:page Controller="Project_AssignUserSelectionClass" >
    <apex:form > 

        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!updateUsers}" value="Assign Users"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!roleWithUsers}" var="roles">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Assigned Roles</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!roles}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Select Users</apex:facet>
                    <apex:selectList id="mgr" value="{!selectedTemplateID}" size="1" style="width:135px;">
                        <!--  <input type="text" style="display:none" id="{!roles}" value="{!selectedTemplateID}"/> -->
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!roleWithUsers[roles]}"></apex:selectOptions>

                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!selectedUsers}" reRender="list">
                        <apex:param name="{!roles}" value="{!roles}" />
                            </apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:selectList> 
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageblock>  
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex :

```
public class Project_AssignUserSelectionClass {

    public MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c projectObject{set;get;}
    public list<MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c> tasklist{set;get;}
    public map<String,list<selectOption>> roleWithUsers {set;get;}
    public set<String> taskUserList{set;get;}
    public list<string> role{set;get;}
    public list<selectOption> userList{set;get;}
    public map<String,list<string>> selectedTemplateID {set;get;}
    public Project_AssignUserSelectionClass()
    {
        try  
        { 
            projectObject=new MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c();
            projectObject.id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); 
            tasklist = new list<MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c> ();
            taskUserList = new set<String>();
            roleWithUsers = new map<String,list<selectOption>> ();
            selectedTemplateID = new map<String,list<string>> ();

            for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c  taskUsers :[select id,name,Assigned_User__c,MPM4_BASE__Assigned_To__c from MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c where MPM4_BASE__Project_Lookup__c = :projectObject.id and (Assigned_User__c != null AND Assigned_User__c != 'None')])
            {
                if(taskUsers.Assigned_User__c != null )
                {
                    taskUserList.add(taskUsers.Assigned_User__c);
                    tasklist.add(taskUsers);
                }
            }

            for(string role: taskUserList)
            {
                userList = new List<selectOption>();
                userList.add(new selectOption('','- None -'));  

                for (User userObj :[SELECT Id,userrole.name,FirstName,LastName FROM User where userrole.name = :role])
                {  
                    String UserName = userObj.FirstName +' '+userObj.LastName;
                    userList.add(new selectOption(userObj.Id, UserName)); 
                } 
                roleWithUsers.put(role,userList);
                selectedTemplateID.put(role,new list<string>());
            } 

        } 
        catch(exception ex)
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.error,ex.getMessage()+' '+ ex.getLineNumber()));
        }
    } 
    public void updateUsers() 
    {
        for(string ss: roleWithUsers.keySet()) 
            {
                system.debug('key '+ss +' values '+ roleWithUsers.get(ss));
                system.debug('templatekey '+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ss'));
            }
    }  
    public void selectedUsers()
    {
        system.debug('selectedTemplateID'+selectedTemplateID);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't work with your code directly since it uses configurations that are specific to your org, but I got something working that I believe is similar to your code.

Controller

```
public class tpc2{

    public map<String,String> selectedTemplateIDs {get; set;}
    public map<String,list<SelectOption>> roleWithUsers {get; set;}
    public String SelectedRole {get; set;}
    public list<String> roles {get; set;}

    public tpc2(){
        roles = new list<String>{'even','odd'};
        selectedTemplateIDs = new map<String,String>{'even'=>'','odd'=>''};

        roleWithUsers = new map<String,list<SelectOption>>{ 
            'even' => new list<SelectOption>{
                new SelectOption('Id2','User 2'),
                new SelectOption('Id4','User 4'),
                new SelectOption('Id6','User 6'),
                new SelectOption('Id8','User 8')
            },
            'odd' => new list<SelectOption>{
                new SelectOption('Id1','User 1'),
                new SelectOption('Id3','User 3'),
                new SelectOption('Id5','User 5'),
                new SelectOption('Id7','User 7')
            }
        };
    }

    public void selectedUsers(){
        system.debug(selectedTemplateIDs);
        system.debug(SelectedRole);
    }

}
```

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page Controller="tpc2"  >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock>


<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!roles}" var="role">
  <apex:column>
    <apex:selectList id="mgr" value="{!selectedTemplateIDs[role]}" size="1" style="width:135px;">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!roleWithUsers[role]}"></apex:selectOptions>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!selectedUsers}" reRender="list">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!SelectedRole}" value="{!role}" name="SelectedRole" />
        </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:selectList> 
   </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>


</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank u for quick reply :) but i need a picklist of users dynamically related to role and also i need to update them salesforce when selected and saved in vf page

Comment: @JyothiPuli Best of luck with your project. Don't be afraid to ask another question if you are having trouble with something else.